# ConcurrentHashMaps and Locks

Tags: java

I have a class like this.

```
public class Cache
{
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Cache> 
        CACHE = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Cache>();

    ConcurrentHashMap<Long,ClassA> mapA = 
        new ConcurrentHashMap<String,ClassA>();

    ConcurrentHashMap<Long,Date> mapB = 
         new ConcurrentHashMap<Long,Date>();

}
```

There are several other methods in the class that add, delete keys from the two maps. 
When a thread updates map A another thread can update mapB for the same Cache instance.
I also need to save this cache to disk at regular intervals. Do I need ReadWriteLocks to maintain
integrity of the data while saving?

Comment: If the operation requires atomicity *between* operations - e.g. either multiple operations on the same CHM or spread between multiple CHMs (or other objects) - then you'll need to account for such.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, ConcurrentHashMaps are internally thread-safe, so you won't need any object locks. [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
>   expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
>   specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of Hashtable. However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail
>   locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in
>   a way that prevents all access.

Comment: But this is only *per* single CHM [method call] and adds *no* atomicity between multiple CHM objects.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the app logic. Eg you safely can iterate over map's entries and save them to a file while other threads are changing the map. But this will be not an atomic operation. If you want a consistent snapshot you'll need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

The writeObject of ConcurrentHashMap locks each segment before serializing, so you do not need to worry about the data integrity. Note: there might be a gap across segments(updates on a non locked segment while Object is getting serialized). If you want full lock during writeObject then use Collections.synchronizedMap().

Refer method ConcurrentHashMap.writeObject():

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        // force all segments for serialization compatibility
        for (int k = 0; k < segments.length; ++k)
            ensureSegment(k);
        s.defaultWriteObject();

        final Segment<K,V>[] segments = this.segments;
        for (int k = 0; k < segments.length; ++k) {
            Segment<K,V> seg = segmentAt(segments, k);
            seg.lock();
            try {
                HashEntry<K,V>[] tab = seg.table;
                for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; ++i) {
                    HashEntry<K,V> e;
                    for (e = entryAt(tab, i); e != null; e = e.next) {
                        s.writeObject(e.key);
                        s.writeObject(e.value);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                seg.unlock();
            }
        }
        s.writeObject(null);
        s.writeObject(null);
    }
```